# Cross - entropy for two variables with different prob. distributions

Tags: algorithms, entropy, mutual-information, genetic-algorithms, cross-entropy

Let us say that we have given two random variables with different prob. distributions:
A = [0.1, 0, 0.5, ...]
B = [0.3, 0.1, 0.03, ...]

What should I do when I want to compute the reformulated cross-entropy between those two?
(log base here is 2)

[image: This is the main equation:]

[image: Where:]

The problem here is when I want to calculate 0.1 * log2(0)....

Should I skip the 0 value and its equivalent prob. from the other set?
Or rather change the zero to another scalar?

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/9302/the-cross-entropy-error-function-in-neural-networks

Comment: Mathematically, infinity would be right answer. Depends on your application... You can just floor at some epsilon